# Setting Size of UIButton Independent of Content

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a row of UIButtons with borders, whose titles will be set to different numbers. As it is, the buttons all resize themselves according to the length of the text inside, but I'd like them to all be the same size, a bit larger than is needed to accomodate the text, as this will look better.

I added borders to the buttons using a subclass in which I specify the following:

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
self.layer.borderWidth = 1
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Is there a way I can specify in absolute terms the size of the rectangle that defines the border around the button? I've tried setting self.frame to a CGRect, but this doesn't seem to affect the border at all.

Comment: self.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,40,40) or  try using Autolayout

Comment: On top @erkamKUCET answer and don't forget it to add this object to the SubView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using storyboards?

If so ctrl and drag your button to the other button you want to be equal widths.

If you aren't using storyboards:

```
constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem:myButton
        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
          toItem: otherButton
       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
      multiplier:1.0f
        constant:0];
```

Let me know if you have any trouble

Comment: Thanks! After setting buttons to equal widths, I realize I can just set a constraint on the width. Much less complicated than I initially thought:)

Answer (score 0):

try titleEdgeInsets property of uibutton. doc is given here:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleEdgeInsets

default is zero which means it will just fit